# Quick Sort Array Random Number Generator Nothing Printed Error

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I have this C code that creates an array with 100 random numbers and I want to sort it using quick sort, but it always gives a Segmentation fault error.

Here is the code:

```
#define MAX 100
int a[MAX];
void quick_sort(double *x, int l, int r) {       
    int l1, r1;

    if (l < r) {       
        l1 = l;
        r1 = r;

        do {       
            while (l1 < r && x[l1 - 1] <= x[l - 1]) {       
                l1++;
            }
            while (l < r1 && x[r1 - 1] >= x[l - 1]) {       
                r1--;
            }
            if (l1 < r1) {       
                swap(&x[l1 - l], &x[r1 - 1]);
            }
        } while (l1 < r1);

        swap(&x[l - 1], &x[r1 - 1]);
        quick_sort(x, l, r1 - 1);
        quick_sort(x, r1 + 1, r);
    }
}

void printArray(int a[], int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    int a_size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 501;
    }
    quick_sort(a, 0, a_size);
    printArray(a, a_size);
}
```

The error is that nothing prints when I run the program.
Can someone help me with the problem?

Comment: Where does `b` points to?

Comment: no memory is allocated for `b`. When you pass it into `quick_sort` (as `x`) and start performing memory accesses on it .. boom

Comment: I would remove it and call `quick_sort` with `a` instead of `b`. At the moment `b` points nowhere, therefore it crashes.

Comment: it says when i use `a` that i can't pass an `int [100]` to a double pointer.

Comment: `quick_sort (a, l, r);` :first argument type is mismatch. and `l` isn't  index. (`int l = a[0];` --> `int l = 0;` ?)

Comment: Presumably `double *x` should be changed to `int *x` in the `quick_sort()` function signature.  But why haven't you shown us an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It would cover what `MAX` is, for example.  If it is less than 100, there's trouble.  Also, why are you not initializing the last two elements of the array?

Comment: `MAX` equals to 100. what do you mean not initializing the last two elements

Comment: you loop from [0, MAX-2) when filling `a` with random numbers, thus leaving out the last 2 elements

Comment: that still doesn't explain why it doesn't print anything

Comment: `#define MAX 100;` --> `#define MAX 100`

Comment: `i <= MAX;` --> `i < MAX;` or `i < a_size`

Comment: `rintArray(a, a_size)` --> `rintArray(a, a_size);`

Comment: `x[l - 1]` ==> `x[0 - 1]` ==> `x[-1]`

Comment: what does your last comment mean?

Comment: If `l` is `0`, `x[l - 1]` ends up accessing an invalid array element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in your code:

- You do not include `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, nor `<time.h>`.
- Your `quick_sort` function expects a pointer to an array of `double`, yet you pass an array of `int`.
- The code for function `swap()` is not posted.
- Your implementation of the Quick Sort algorithm in function `quick_sort` is flawed:

  - you should not scan slices of size `1`, use `(r - l > 1)`.
  - You cannot use `x[l - 1]` as pivot, it is not even part of the slice to be sorted.  Furthermore, you should extract the pivot from the array before the swapping phase as it may move.
  - You should not name a variable `l`, it looks too close to `1` and you do make the mistake here: `swap(&x[l1 - l], &x[r1 - 1]);`
  - You should initialize `l1` and `r1` such that you do not need to subtract `1` in so many places, it leads to confusion and erroneous code.
  - Study the algorithms from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and translate one to C.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 100

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int x = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = x;
}

// Quick Sort using Hoare's original partition scheme
void quick_sort(int *x, int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int pivot = x[l];
        int l1 = l - 1;
        int r1 = r;

        for (;;) {
            while (x[++l1] < pivot)
                continue;

            while (x[--r1] > pivot)
                continue;

            if (l1 < r1) {
                swap(&x[l1], &x[r1]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        quick_sort(x, l, r1 + 1);
        quick_sort(x, r1 + 1, r);
    }
}

void printArray(int a[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int a[MAX];
    int a_size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 501;
    }
    quick_sort(a, 0, a_size);

    printArray(a, a_size);
    return 0;
}
```